# Close <details> when another opens

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make so that when a user opens a `<details>` it will close all other open `<details>` views. Not sure how to do it. Any suggestions

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/77oqerc6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('details').click(function(){
      $('details').not(this).removeAttr('open');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/77oqerc6/2/

Comment: That does just hide all my other details. It just need to close them. Not make them disapere :)

Comment: you have not provided any code. so all I can do is guessing. I'm just suggestion the way, you should change it according to your needs

Comment: I have now added a Jsfiddle. Where you can see what i mean i hope :) As you see there, when you opens another title, is should hide the other description automaticly :)

Comment: @unscope was it the solution you were looking for?

Comment: Sorry @Ashkan i went to bed! Yeah totaly what i was looking for thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

By "close," do you mean remove from the web page? If so, this should work:

```
$('details').click(function(){
     $('details').not(this).detach();
});
```